# Order of decorations in Decorator Pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, decorator

Most of you know the pizza / cofee example for the decorator pattern.

```
Pizza* pizza1 = BigPizzaDecorator(MushromDecorator(SimplePizza()));
Pizza* pizza2 = MushromDecorator(BigPizzaDecorator(SimplePizza()));
```

the two object behave in a similar way, but not completely, in particular if you have non-commutative operation, for example:

```
BigPizzaDecorator::price() { return 10 + PizzaDecorator::price(); }  // this is commutative
BigPizzaDecorator::name() { return "big " + PizzaDecorator::name(); } // this is not commutative
```

So the price for `pizza1` and `pizza2` are the same, but the name is not, for example the first should be `"Big mushroom pizza"`, the second `"Mushroom big pizza"`. The first is english correct (probably better would be "Big pizza with mushroom", but it's not so important).

The book "Head first" point out this problem with the Cofee example:

> When you need to peek at multiple layers into the decorator chain, you
>   are starting to push the decorator beyond its true intent.
>
> Nevertheless, such things are possible. Imagine a CondimentPrettyPrint
>   decorator that parses the final decription and can print “Mocha, Whip,
>   Mocha” as “Whip, Double Mocha.”

what is the best way to do that? (`operator<` ?)

Comment: it's not important which one, the point is that I want the same output for `pizza1.name()` and `pizza2.name()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ive never known this sort of thing to be needed when using decorators.  And I would think that if you need to do this, then you shouldn't be using decorators, especially as you're knowingly "pushing the decorator beyond it's intent".

I have had a stab at doing this, the code is below.  Basically, I create a thin layer around the `SimplePizza` object that understands what the decorators need, then the decorators decorate that.

The main problem here, is that to maintain order in the output, you would have to maintain a relationship between decorators - which can quickly become a maintenance nightmare.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <sstream>

struct name_part
{
    std::string mName;
    int         mPriority;

    name_part(const std::string& name, int priority)
    : mName(name)
    , mPriority(priority)
    {
    }
};

bool operator<(const name_part& a, const name_part& b)
{
    return (a.mPriority < b.mPriority);
}

std::string priority_queueToString(const std::priority_queue<name_part>& orig)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    std::priority_queue<name_part> q(orig);

    while (!q.empty())
    {
        oss << q.top().mName << " ";
        q.pop();
    }

    return oss.str();
}

struct SimplePizza
{
    virtual std::string name()
    {
        return "pizza";
    }
};

struct SimplePizzaImplementer : SimplePizza
{
    SimplePizza *mDecorated;

    SimplePizzaImplementer()
    : mDecorated(0)
    {
    }

    SimplePizzaImplementer(SimplePizza *decorated)
    : mDecorated(decorated)
    {
    }

    virtual std::string name()
    {
        return priority_queueToString(nameParts());
    }

    virtual std::priority_queue<name_part> nameParts()
    {
        std::priority_queue<name_part> q;

        if (mDecorated)
        {
            q.push(name_part(mDecorated->name(), 0));
        }

        return q;
    }
};

struct MushroomDecorator : SimplePizzaImplementer
{
    SimplePizzaImplementer *mDecorated;

    MushroomDecorator(SimplePizzaImplementer *decorated)
    : mDecorated(decorated)
    {
    }

    virtual std::string name()
    {
        return priority_queueToString(nameParts());
    }

    virtual std::priority_queue<name_part> nameParts()
    {
        std::priority_queue<name_part> q = mDecorated->nameParts();
        q.push(name_part("mushroom", 1));
        return q;
    }
};

struct BigDecorator : SimplePizzaImplementer
{
    SimplePizzaImplementer *mDecorated;

    BigDecorator(SimplePizzaImplementer *decorated)
    : mDecorated(decorated)
    {
    }

    virtual std::string name()
    {
        return priority_queueToString(nameParts());
    }

    virtual std::priority_queue<name_part> nameParts()
    {
        std::priority_queue<name_part> q = mDecorated->nameParts();
        q.push(name_part("big", 2));
        return q;
    }
};

int main()
{
    SimplePizzaImplementer *impl = new SimplePizzaImplementer(new SimplePizza());
    SimplePizza *pizza1 = new MushroomDecorator(new BigDecorator(impl));
    SimplePizza *pizza2 = new BigDecorator(new MushroomDecorator(impl));

    std::cout << pizza1->name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << pizza2->name() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In terms of where to put such code, have an overloaded operator<< is feasible.

I feel that the "pushing the decorator beyond it's intent" really needs emphasis here.

Would you really build a serious application whose functioning depends on parsing

```
"Mocha, Whip, Mocha"
```

and formulating

```
"Whip, Double Mocha"
```

Conceptually you are inferring semantics from an interface that is not published with that intent. The result will be very brittle, minor changes in implementations of decorators: "Yummy super mocha special" would break the parser. Adding new decorators would require unknown levels of change.

Comment: how can I implement it? I'm thinking about another solution: define an enum like `enum DecoratorEnum {MUSHROOM=1, BIG=2, ...}`, pass a vector of `DecoratorEnum` to a factory that first sort them, and then return your object decorated, so `MushroomDecorator` is applayied first. For example `Pizza *pizza = DecorateObject(SimplePizza, {BIG, MUSHROOM})` Good?

Comment: my suspicion is that if you have non-commutative decorators, you probably also have decorators that cannot be recombined arbitrarily. So ( A, B, C = good; B, A, C = bad; But how about A, C? or B, D ). I suspect that you need to drop the decorator patter for the printing piece.